# Google Maps not working on jquery mobile framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Google maps is not working on jquery mobile in my phonegap application. But when i run same code without using JQM it is working...tell me what i am doing wrong in the below code

HTML

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

plz refer this for full code 
https://jsbin.com/fanixajebi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give to your data-role page an id

and after use the event of the framework for initialize the page.
And give an height size in px not in %

ex:

```html
<div id="home" data-role="page">
```

```js
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#home", function(event) {    /*  pagebeforeshow  */       
  setTimeout("initialize()",100);
});
```